# Как разрешить просмотр фотографий с s3 amazon?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

Подскажите, как открыть доступ к просмотру изображений с s3 amazon?

```
https://florachaing-ru.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/tmp/products/b9cf640af0dbdf8ac0884359c15741dc.jpg
```

Управление с ларавел все ок, но когда пытаюсь открыть изображение вне фрейма, пишет: доступ запрещен...

Comment: Попробуйте изменить доступ в IAM

Comment: а что нужно выбирать, первый раз работаю и чет не могу понять как включить видимость